# SSRS 2008 R2 Change Shared Data Source for Production vs Test

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to figure out the best way to mitigate this situation.  My project team consists of 3 developers each with their own instances of SSRS installed.  We have 2 external SSRS servers that we must push updates to in order for the customer to review and for us to test and there is a 3rd external server coming online that will not be administered by us.

I have been trying to find a way to set the Shared Data Source to the current environment regardless of the system it is on.  I had thought that just a common naming convention for the ReportServer address would be fine, but we've already found them to be inconsistent on the production and test servers.  My next attempt was to specify an ODBC connection and let each person create a system DSN with connection information, but after an entire day of messing with it and continually getting errors, I'm not convinced it's the way to go.  ( The most recent error being "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application" ). I have tried going through Windows ODBC DSN msc to create the DSN and I have tried using Report Builder 3.0 to create one and neither seem to work.

So I guess at this point I just have to ask, is there a best practice for going about this? I'd like to do local development and testing via the "Run" button inside Report Builder and then I'd just like to upload the file to the Report Manager and have it work regardless of the URL for the Report Server.

Answer (score 2):

If the properties (connectionstring, etc) for shared data sources don't change much on your servers, the following may work for you: in the properties for your project set `OverwriteDataSources = False` for the appropriate configurations. Set it to true only temporarily to change the data source, if needed.

That way any dev can safely deploy to the servers, without affecting the data source, even if (s)he locally changed something (e.g. the connection string) to match a personal environment.

Not an optimal solution, but relatively easy to set up.